# Can Google Analytics v4 handle uncaught exceptions?

Tags: android, google-analytics

Google Analytics v4 [claims to be capable of reporting uncaught exceptions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/exceptions#uncaught). However, the [evidence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23854534/analytics-v4-uncaught-exceptions-not-working) [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001136/how-create-detailed-stack-traces-in-google-analytics-v4-crash-reports-for-uncaug) [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351648/how-to-get-google-analytics-v4-to-report-uncaught-exceptions-crashes-for-my-ap) [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820153/reporting-uncaught-exceptions-using-google-analytics-v4) [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820904/reporting-uncaught-exceptions-using-google-analytics-v4-workaround). Accordingly, my question is: can Google Analytics v4 handle uncaught exceptions? If so, can someone provide a minimal example?

Answer (score 0):

I found this and use it in my project:

```
 private void uncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler myHandler = new ExceptionReporter(easyTracker,
                GAServiceManager.getInstance(),
                Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(), this);

        // Make myHandler the new default uncaught exception handler.
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(myHandler);
    }
```

and you have to call this method in onCreate:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    easyTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(this);

    uncaughtExceptionHandler();

    //
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like v4 code, it looks like either v3 or v2.